# RuleAgent authentication fails in integration with drools-guvnor5.1

Tags: integration, basic-authentication, drools-guvnor

I have deployed drools-guvnor5.1.war to tomcat6. everything looks fine in logs.however when I call one of the package from a different application,auth fails.

```
RuleAgent(default) INFO (Tue Jan 27 17:49:09 IST 2015): Configuring with newInstance=true, secondsToRefresh=5
RuleAgent(default) INFO (Tue Jan 27 17:49:09 IST 2015): Configuring package provider : URLScanner monitoring URLs:  http://localhost:8083/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/TEST/LATEST
RuleAgent(default) EXCEPTION (Tue Jan 27 17:49:09 IST 2015): Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8083/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/TEST/LATEST. Stack trace should follow.
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8083/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/TEST/LATEST
```

JAVA code

```
RuleAgent agent = RuleAgent.newRuleAgent(properties);
```

Properties

```
newInstance=true
url=http://localhost:9090/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/TEST/LATEST
poll=5
enableBasicAuthentication=true
userName=admin
password=admin
```

On debugging further I find that it fails UrlScanner class

```
    private Package readPackage(URL u) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
         return httpClient.fetchPackage( u );
    }
```

I cant switch to KnowledgeAgent because its a legacy application.
pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find a correct solution. however I switched to KnowledgeAgent, where I read changeset.xml for drools configuration.